# Get black friday dates in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

How to get black friday dates in Postgres ?
IT will be the last friday of November month, is it possible to get it somehow ?

Comment: Please edit your question to show your work, as well as what you're expecting as input and output (and where you're running into problems).

Comment: Last Friday of November isn't the definition. It's the Friday following the 4th Thursday in November (US Thanksgiving). Which means it'll be the 23rd in some years, not the 30th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon the answer from [Frank Heikens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70125134/5298879) (much better than my first answer, now deleted) with the corrected Black Friday definition from [@Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever)

```
select  ("November Thursdays"+'1 day'::interval)::date as "Black Fridays"
from
(   SELECT  "date"::date "November Thursdays",
            row_number() over (partition by EXTRACT(year FROM "date") order by "date")
    FROM    generate_series('2000-01-01'::date, 
                            '2051-01-01'::date, 
                            INTERVAL '1 day') dates("date")
    WHERE   EXTRACT(month from "date") = 11 -- November
    AND     EXTRACT(dow FROM "date") = 4 -- Thursday
    ORDER BY 1) Thursdays
where row_number=4;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use MAX() to get the last Friday in November:

```
    SELECT  MAX(d)::date AS black_friday
    FROM    generate_series('2000-01-01'::timestamp, '2051-01-01'::timestamp, INTERVAL '1 day') g(d)
    WHERE   EXTRACT(month from d) = 11 -- November
    AND     EXTRACT(dow FROM d) = 5 -- Friday
    AND     EXTRACT(DAY FROM d) BETWEEN 23 AND 29
    GROUP BY
        EXTRACT(year FROM d)
    ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Like I said in a comment, the actual commonly accepted definition isn't "last Friday in November". Simplest way to compute it is the day of the month must be between 23 and 29 (inclusive).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: You can add that condition to the WHERE condition